# How to transform huge txt file to have fixed number of words per line?

Tags: python, text, bigdata

I have huge txt file like this (`input.txt`):

```
word1 word2 word3 word2
word5
word6 word7 word8 word9 word10
```

I want to transform it to have *3* words per line like this (`output.txt`):

```
word1 word2 word3 
word2 word5 word6 
word7 word8 word9 
word10
```

Of course last line could have less than *3* words.

**Note 1:** *3* is a parameter (more realistic value is 200)

**Note 2:** words are separated by space, so they could be obtained by `split(" ")`

I've solution that works when I can load whole `input.txt` into memory and process it, but my `input.txt` is around 300GB so it doesn't fit. Loading whole `input.txt` is not necesarry, as I think it could be processed in 'stream fashion' so no real memory problem, but it shouldn't take ages.

Pure python solution would be great, but if more performant or concise solution with some popular library exist, that also will be fine.

Comment: This sounds contradictory to me: `I've solution that works when I can load whole input.txt into memory and process it, but my input.txt is around 300GB so it doesn't fit.`

Comment: It would be easier to convert original file into several files limited by a certain number of lines.  That's not an option?

Comment: If I've file of size e.g. less than 1GB I can load it whole to memory and basically this is fiddling with list of lists, but I can't load 300GB, so it need to be done "bit by bit"

Comment: Your best bet is to use the syntax `with open("file.txt") as f: for line in f: ...`, as described in [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines)

Comment: @crissal I've hoped that there is "higher level solution", processing line by line would be a little tricky, as I need to accumulate enough words to create line in output file

Comment: You can also `f.read(anyAmountOfBytes)` you like, like `1`, and build around it your own text parser

Comment: @FiddlingBits I think "that works when I can" was intended as "that would work if I could".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the input file line by line and using a `deque` as a "buffer of words" that you empty when needed should be memory efficient.

```py
from collections import deque
from itertools import islice

WORDS_PER_LINE = 3

buffer = deque()
with open("input.txt") as f_in, open("output.txt", "wt") as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        buffer.extend(line.split())
        while len(buffer) >= WORDS_PER_LINE:
            f_out.write(" ".join((buffer.popleft() for _ in range(WORDS_PER_LINE))) + "\n")

    f_out.write(" ".join(islice(buffer, WORDS_PER_LINE)) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a lazy iterator of words in the file:

```
def words_of(fileobj):
    """Given a file-like object, generate its words.
    Does not open or close the file. Yields words from the current point."""
    for line in fileobj:
        yield from line.split()
```

Then set up to [iterate in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/), using one of the versions that accepts a lazy iterator:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Then simply iterate over the input and write to the output:

```
def regroup(ifile, ofile, size):
    with open(ifile) as f_in, open(ofile, 'w') as f_out:
        for group in grouper(words_of(f_in), size):
            f_out.write(' '.join(group) + '\n')
```